# Program keeps returning cannot read property toLowerCase of Undefined

Tags: javascript

```
function isIsogram(str) {

    if (typeof str === undefined) {
        return true
    }

    var passing = true;
    var strn = str.toLowerCase()
    var counts = {}

    for (i = 0; i <= strn.length; i++) {
        var letter = strn.charAt(i)

        if (counts[letter]) {
            counts[letter] = 1 + counts[letter]
        } else {
            counts[letter] = 1
        }

        if(counts[letter] > 1) {
            return passing = false
        }
    }
    return passing
}
```

After running this code against the tests I keep getting; TypeError: Cannot read property `'toLowerCase'` of undefined. Please how do I resolve this and what am I getting wrong?

Comment: This code is working for me. I'm running the function like this: `console.log( isIsogram("subdermatoglyphic") )` and getting `true` Since you require a string for this to work, you should consider testing for `'string'` instead of `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `"undefined"`.

e.g.

```
if (typeof str === "undefined")
```

But you could replace the line with this which would also check for null parameters.

```
if (!str) {
  return true;
}
```

e.g.

```js
function isIsogram(str) {

  if (!str) {
    return true;
  }

  var passing = true;

  var strn = str.toLowerCase();

  var counts = {};

  for (i = 0; i <= strn.length; i++) {

    var letter = strn.charAt(i);

    if (counts[letter]) {
      counts[letter] = 1 + counts[letter];
    } else {
      counts[letter] = 1;
    }

    if (counts[letter] > 1) {
      return passing = false;
    }

  }

  return passing;
}

console.log(isIsogram());
console.log(isIsogram(null));
console.log(isIsogram("asdf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

two things ...

first you could try..

```
if (str == undefined) {
    return true;
}
```

instead of using 'typeof'

or secondly put the "var strn = str.toLowerCase()" into a try/catch to catch the error..

```
try {
    var strn = str.toLowerCase();
} catch (e) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve,the first if statement worked for me then I checked for an empty string and the code ran.                                                                    if (str == undefined) {
    return true;
}